# VBA Code for Command button to sort form?

Tags: forms

Good Morning,

I have just joined stackoverflow in the hope of improving my VBA Skills, and subsequently by database skills.

I am However stuck on a sort problem on one of my forms.  The Form is called "Frm_Civil", and is generated using a query called "Tbl_Civil Query", the query is sorted on the field's Reg1,Reg2 & Reg3.  I would like to put a button on my form to sort the form into Type1, Type2 & Type3.

I have read through some questions on stack Overflow and came across the following code, but i am having trouble adapting it to my needs :

Private Sub Command17_Click()

```
Dim strDirection As String
strDirection = Me.OrderBy

If strDirection Like "* DESC" Then
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSortAscending
Else
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSortDescending
End If
Me.OrderByOn = True
```

End Sub

Do I change the Dim name, and if so how do i specify three field's to be sorted ?

Many thanks in advance for any advice

Best Regards

Keith

I tried to adapt existing code to my needs